# Context free grammar to Chomsky's normal form

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

\begin{align*}
S&\to AACD\\
A&\to aAb\\
C&\to aC\mid a\\
D&\to aDa\mid bdb\mid\varepsilon
\end{align*}

I think that this grammar is infinite so it is not possible to convert it into cnf. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Every context-free grammar can be converted to Chomsky normal form. Also, note that grammars are by definition finite: a grammar might describe infinitely many strings, but the grammar itself is finite.

Comment: What will be it's cnf form ?

Comment: All the standard references explain how to convert a grammar to CNF.

Comment: S is not terminating. That's what the confusion is. I'm unable to convert it.